# jQuery $(window).resize duplicate to $(document).ready to resize and reposition elements

Tags: jquery, resize, window-resize

I have this jQuery to set a slider functions. This slider is the whole screen width and height, so when I resize the window, i need it to recalculate those sizes. I tried to duplicate the same codes on both triggers, but it didn't change anything. Can you guys help please?

The code on $(document).ready is the following:

```
qtPhotos = $('#slider ul li').length;
windowWidth = $(window).width();
windowHeight = $(window).height();

$('#slider').width(windowWidth).height(alturaJanela);
$('#slider > ul').width(windowWidth * qtPhotos);
$('#slider > ul > li').width(windowWidth).height(windowHeight);

$('#slider > ul > li:first').before($('#slider > ul > li:last'));
$('#slider > ul').css('marginLeft', '-'+windowWidth+'px');

$('#seta-next').click(function(){
    $('#slider > ul').stop(true, true).animate({'left': "-="+windowWidth+"px"}, 500, 'easeInQuad', function(){
        $('#slider > ul > li:last').after($('#slider > ul > li:first'));
        $('#slider > ul').css("left", "+="+windowWidth+"px");
    });
}); 

$('#seta-prev').click(function(){
    $('#slider > ul').stop(true, true).animate({'left': "+="+windowWidth+"px"}, 500, 'easeInQuad', function(){
        $('#slider > ul > li:first').before($('#slider > ul > li:last'));
        $('#slider > ul').css("left", "-="+windowWidth+"px");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That entire block of code would need to be wrapped in a $(window).resize() . Have you got it like that already?

So -

```
$(window).resize(function() {

// all your code here 

}).trigger("resize");
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work... Is this .trigger("resize"); realy needed? I never used it and it worked just fine for other needs...

Comment: trigger("resize") just makes sure that the resize is triggered on first load of the page. I have found that it is better to do if you want the resize function to calculate heights etc on first load of the page, rather then just when you resize it. It just depends on your project. I don't understand how that could not be working just to recalculate the widths and heights. To you have a URL so I can see the code?

Comment: makes sense... i will test if it works, but probably will. thank you